# How to combine duplicate rows in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, transformation

Given a dataframe (**my_data**) in R such as the following

```
category  Keyword1 Keyword2 Keyword3 Keyword4 Keyword5 Keyword6 Keyword7 Keyword8
123         0        1         1       0         0        0       0         1
155         1        0         0       0         1        0       1         1
144         0        0         1       0         0        0       1         1
123         1        1         0       0         0        0       1         1
```

I want to transform the dataframe by taking rows with category id values that already exist (e.g category **123**) and combine them. The result should look like:

```
category Keyword1 Keyword2 Keyword3 Keyword4 Keyword5 Keyword6 Keyword7 Keyword8
123         1        1         1       0         0        0       0         1
155         1        0         0       0         1        0       1         1
144         0        0         1       0         0        0       1         1
```

How can I do this in R ?

Comment: i think you want `aggregate(.~category, data=df, FUN=max)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dplyr`, which is useful for many other such use cases as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %>% group_by(category) %>% summarise_each(funs(max))
```

Output is:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 9
  category Keyword1 Keyword2 Keyword3 Keyword4 Keyword5 Keyword6 Keyword7 Keyword8
     <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
1      123        1        1        1        0        0        0        1        1
2      144        0        0        1        0        0        0        1        1
3      155        1        0        0        0        1        0        1        1
```

Comment: Is it possible to get both the Keyword1 value of rows with same category as "0, 1"? This is an alternative of doing a summation like above. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Gopala this is what i was looking for my microbiome data and it works perfectly fine thanks a ton