# Compress dataframe in length with almost duplicate rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that is way bigger than it needs to be. Due to necessary transformations beforehand, I receive a dataframe looking like this:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.5 | 3 | 2 | a | 0 | 0 |
| 1.5 | 3 | 2 | 0 | b | 0 |
| 1.5 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 0 | c |

This is what it should look like afterwards:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.5 | 3 | 2 | a | b | c |

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

The second problem is that values are vertically listed, even though they could be next to each other. Example:

| A1 | A2 | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.5 | NA | 2 |
| 1.5 | NA | 2 |
| 2.5 | NA | 2 |

Instead, I want this:

| A1 | A2 | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.5 | 2.5 | 2 |

Comment: Are you using R or pandas?

Comment: I am using R...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine duplicate rows in a data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060599/how-to-combine-duplicate-rows-in-a-data-frame-in-r)

Comment: This tackles the first problem, however not the second one but I am going to check it out, thanks

Comment: Why should A2 be equal to 2.5?

Comment: Initially, I have multiple records for one user in a column but since I want to have one row per user, I want all his A-values in row, starting with A1 up until AX with X as the number of different values...I need to have a final dataframe where each row represents exactly one user. Don't get distracted by the column names (A1, A2, etc.), those are irrelevant placeholder names